# sending large sql queries as input to a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I wrote a procedure that will automatically get the data from the given query and put the reuslt data set into a file in directory with delimiters. It works good for smaller queries like `select * from table_1` but not for big queries like :

```
SELECT
   i.row_id,
   translate(i.x_notes_txt, chr(10)||chr(13)||'|' , '   '),
   null
FROM communication i,
     contact c
WHERE   i.last_upd >= (SELECT to_char(last_updated_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
FROM extract_status
WHERE extract_nm = 'INTN300')
   AND i.last_upd < sysdate
   AND i.x_interaction_type_cd NOT IN ('XRAC','FMS','ATV','IRL')
   AND i.pr_con_id  = c.row_id
   AND c.x_Prospect_Ind = 'Y';
```

while calling procedure that accepts query procdure : - `tab_to_flat('with_the_above_query')` it is showing errors like

```
1) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "|" .
2) Encountered the symbol "),
               null
       FROM    communication i,
```

And many more ..Can anybody help how to pass these queries as a input????

```
        /* Formatted on 06/06/2013 1:42:56 PM (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_flat (input_query   IN CLOB,
                                    dir_name      IN VARCHAR2,
                                    file_name     IN VARCHAR2,
                                    seperator     IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
  IS
   c_seperator          VARCHAR2 (3) := ' ';
   incoming_seperator   VARCHAR2 (3) := seperator;
   no_of_rows           NUMBER;
   rec_tab              DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
   col_cnt              INTEGER;
   src_id               INTEGER DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
   val_varchar          VARCHAR2 (32767);
   val_num              NUMBER;
  val_date             DATE;
   file_input           UTL_FILE.file_type;
   l_start              NUMBER;
   row_cnt              NUMBER := 0;
   BEGIN
   l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

    file_input :=
  UTL_FILE.fopen (dir_name,
                  file_name,
                  'w',
                  32767);
   DBMS_SQL.parse (src_id, input_query, 1);

  DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (src_id, col_cnt, rec_tab);

  FOR i IN 1 .. col_cnt
  LOOP
  CASE (rec_tab (i).col_type)
     WHEN 1
     THEN
        DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id,
                                i,
                                val_varchar,
                                32767);
     WHEN 2
     THEN
        DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id, i, val_num);
     --when 8 then dbms_sql.define_column_long(src_id,i);
     WHEN 12
     THEN
        DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id, i, val_date);
     ELSE
        DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id,
                                i,
                                val_varchar,
                                32767);
    END CASE;
    END LOOP;

   no_of_rows := DBMS_SQL.execute (src_id);

  LOOP
  EXIT WHEN (DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (src_id) <= 0);
  c_seperator := ' ';

  FOR j IN 1 .. col_cnt
  LOOP
     CASE (rec_tab (j).col_type)
        WHEN 1
        THEN
           DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_varchar);
           UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_varchar);
        WHEN 2
        THEN
           DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_num);
           UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_num);
        -- when 8 then dbms_sql.column_value_long(src_id,j,4000,1);

        WHEN 12
        THEN
           DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_date);
           UTL_FILE.put (
              file_input,
              c_seperator || TO_CHAR (val_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
        ELSE
           DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_varchar);
           UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_varchar);
     END CASE;

     c_seperator := incoming_seperator;
  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.new_line (file_input);
  row_cnt := row_cnt + 1;
     END LOOP;

     DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (src_id);

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
  'The execution time is : ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start));
                    RETURN row_cnt;
       EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          IF (SQLCODE = -942)
           THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Please check the table_name');
           ELSE
           RAISE;
          END IF;
         END;
```

Comment: does that big query work ? what i mean is, does it show the correct results?

Comment: ya it works well ... but i am worried how to send it as a input to dat procedure

Comment: so basically you want the result from the big query to be passed as input parameter to that procedure?

Comment: no actually i need the query to be passed into procedure.. any query.. i am new to oracle.. is there any way we can send any type of query as a input to that procedure... in that procedure i am using dbms_sql package to parse and use it..

Comment: It is also showing error for 'DD-MON-YYYY',('XRAC','FMS','ATV','IRL') and 'INTN300' also...

Comment: @user2401828 Is your sql query is dynamic in nature? Why not pass values to procedure and create a dynamic query within the procedure?

Comment: actually the query given will be dynamic and i wont be knowing the record strucuture of the query output.. so since the query is also dynamic the procedure must accept any type of select query we use.

Comment: @user2401828 Paste all the errors that you get. Maybe i can figure out where to look more precisely. I want to mention that i am not very familiar with DBMS_sql...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just aren't escaping the quotes that are included in the query string, so you're calling it as

```
tab_to_flat('SELECT i.row_id, translate(i.x_notes_txt, chr(10)||chr(13)||'|' , '   '),...')
```

The single quote around the `|` you're concatenating after the `chr(13)` is the immediate problem, but there are others. You could either go through and carefully double-up every quote inside the string:

```
tab_to_flat('SELECT i.row_id, translate(i.x_notes_txt, chr(10)||chr(13)||''|'' , ''   ''),...')
```

... or more readibly use the [quoted value syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617):

```
tab_to_flat(q'[SELECT i.row_id, translate(i.x_notes_txt, chr(10)||chr(13)||'|' , '   '),...]')
```

... where the `q'[ ... ]'` enclose your original string and allow you to use single quote marks without having to escape them. You just need to be sure that the actual query doesn't contain `[` or `]`, or pick different delimiters if it does.

This says nothing about whether what you're doing is a good approach and if you can find a better way to approach your problem, and doesn't address SQL injection etc.; this is just to fix the problem with what you're currently calling and how you're doing it.

Comment: @user2401828 - it's the 'alternate quoting mechanism'. It's described in the [text literal documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) I linked to in the answer; look for the bullet points under 'In the bottom branch of the syntax'.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use am oracle cursor like this :

```
FUNCTION SELECT_FROM_MY_TABLE(v_QUERY_TO_BE_EXECUTED    VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
    c_my_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN c_my_cursor FOR
    v_QUERY_TO_BE_EXECUTED -- When working with Ref Cursors, open-for can be used directly, instead of execute immediate. 

  RETURN  c_my_cursor;

END SELECT_FROM_MY_TABLE;
```

So basically you have a function, that returns a cursor which contains the information from your query. When you use the cursor, you do it like this :

```
PROCEDURE procedure_use_cursor
IS
    c_my_cursor       SYS_REFCURSOR;
    r_my_table_row    my_table%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  c_my_cursor := SELECT_FROM_MY_TABLE;

  LOOP

  FETCH c_my_cursor INTO r_my_table_row;
  EXIT WHEN c_my_cursor%NOTFOUND ;

  -- do what you want with r_my_table_row   

 END LOOP;

END procedure_use_cursor;
```

Comment: Thank you Teshte.. But i am looking for a different answer since the query is also dynamic... i will be getting the query dynamically..

Comment: @user2401828 how about if we give a parameter to my function, that is basically a query in the form of a string, and by using `execute immediate`, we put the results from it in a cursor ?

Comment: I am making the procedure generic one.. so that it will accept any quer and put that into a flat file.. i am putting the procedure also..

Comment: that is a gud idea... Can you plz give a little example??

Comment: Actually i tried for other solution like taking result to cursor.. convert it into ref_cursor then by using dbms_sql.to_cursor_id convert it into cursor id.. dat was easy.. but that to_cursor_id is introduced in 11g... i am using 10.6(:

Comment: so now, you have a function, that takes a query as a string, and returns a cursor, that contains the results of the query. What do you want to do with the results?

Comment: create or replace function tab_to_flat(input_query in clob,dir_name in varchar2,file_name in varchar2,seperator in varchar2) return number is 

   c_seperator          VARCHAR2 (3) := ' ';
   incoming_seperator   VARCHAR2 (3) := seperator;
   no_of_rows           NUMBER;
   rec_tab              DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
   col_cnt              INTEGER;
   src_id               INTEGER DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
   val_varchar          VARCHAR2 (32767);
   val_num              NUMBER;
   val_date             DATE;

Comment: file_input           UTL_FILE.file_type;
   l_start              NUMBER;
   row_cnt              NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
   l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

   file_input :=
      UTL_FILE.fopen (dir_name,
                      file_name,
                      'w',
                      32767);

Comment: DBMS_SQL.parse (src_id, input_query , 1);

   DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (src_id, col_cnt, rec_tab);

   FOR i IN 1 .. col_cnt
   LOOP
      CASE (rec_tab (i).col_type)
         WHEN 1
         THEN
            DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id,
                                    i,
                                    val_varchar,
                                    32767);

Comment: WHEN 2
         THEN
            DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id, i, val_num);
         --when 8 then dbms_sql.define_column_long(src_id,i);
         WHEN 12
         THEN
            DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id, i, val_date);
         ELSE
            DBMS_SQL.define_column (src_id,
                                    i,
                                    val_varchar,
                                    32767);
      END CASE;
   END LOOP;

Comment: no_of_rows := DBMS_SQL.execute (src_id);

   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN (DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (src_id) <= 0);
      c_seperator := ' ';

      FOR j IN 1 .. col_cnt
      LOOP
         CASE (rec_tab (j).col_type)
            WHEN 1
            THEN
               DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_varchar);
               UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_varchar);

Comment: WHEN 2
            THEN
               DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_num);
               UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_num);
            -- when 8 then dbms_sql.column_value_long(src_id,j,4000,1);

            WHEN 12
            THEN
               DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_date);
               UTL_FILE.put (
                  file_input,
                  c_seperator || TO_CHAR (val_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

Comment: ELSE
               DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (src_id, j, val_varchar);
               UTL_FILE.put (file_input, c_seperator || val_varchar);
         END CASE;

         c_seperator := incoming_seperator;
      END LOOP;

      UTL_FILE.new_line (file_input);
      row_cnt := row_cnt + 1;
   END LOOP;

Comment: DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (src_id);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      'The execution time is : ' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start));
      return row_cnt;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
            IF (SQLCODE = -942)
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Please check the table_name');
      ELSE
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;